# spamassassin stop fowrwarding spam

Tags: email, ubuntu, vps, spamassassin

i have an ubuntu VPS with spamassassin configured however I still get the spam emails as an attachment and with subject label "SPAM".

what I would like instead is to drop those email completely instead of getting them marked as spam.

Answer (score 0):

Spamassassin only handles classification of incoming emails. It does not have any features for setting the actual email in any direction, or delete the email.

There are some suggested solutions for auto-deleting emails marked as spam by SA. Google "postfix delete spam" to read up on some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here I had to setup header flags in postfix

http://www.halfslide.com/dropping-spam-with-postfix-and-spamassassin-on-godaddys-dedicated-servers/